# Working with Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a sudent starting to learn Javascript.  We're working with arrays.  The question I have is when working with two arrays, how can I match indexes when one index is chosen.  Example:

```
var nameArray = [ "Earl", "John", "Shelia", "Lenny" ];

var testScoreArray = [ 85, 92, 87, 99 ];
```

If you chose Lenny, I want to be able to match his score with his name and vice versa.  The arrays aren't fixed and are part of a program that can add names and scores at any time.  I understand you can program it to store the names and test scores as a multi-dimensional array but not for this example.

I would like to be able to look a score up based on it being the lowest, highest or another situation and match the score with the name and vise versa.

Comment: Can you add a score without a name associated with it? Can there be a name without a score?

Comment: just use that index on the other array? array2[index]? if you can't assume they're in the same position it's not possible they way you're trying to do it

Answer (score 2):

Given this:

```
var array1 = ['Earl', 'John', 'Shelia', 'Lenny']
```

… you can get the index of "Lenny" like this:

```
array1.indexOf('Lenny');  //3
```

So you simply need to plug that into the other array:

```
array2[array1.indexOf('Lenny')] //99
```

**Snippet**

```js
var array1 = ['Earl', 'John', 'Shelia', 'Lenny'],
    array2 = [85,92,87,99]

console.log(array2[array1.indexOf('Lenny')]); //99
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I'm trying the suggestions to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure that you are looking for is a [bidirectional map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map). Description from Wikipedia:

> In [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science), a **bidirectional map**, or **hash bag**, is an [associative data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) in which the `(key, value)` pairs form a [one-to-one correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_correspondence). Thus the [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) is [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_relationship) in each direction: `value` can also act as a key to `key`. A pair `(a, b)` thus provides a [unique coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between `a` and `b` so that `b` can be found when `a` is used as a key and `a` can be found when `b` is used as a key.

Mathematically, a bidirectional map between keys and values is equivalent to a pair of functions:

1. A function `f` from keys to values (i.e. `a -> b`).
2. A function `g` from values to keys (i.e. `b -> a`).

In addition, there are two constraints imposed on bidirectional maps:

1. Given any key `x` the constraint `g (f x) = x` must be satisfied.
2. Given any value `y` the constraint `f (g y) = y` must be satisfied.

Therefore, `Bimap(a, b) = (a -> b, b -> a)`.

Alternatively, a bidirectional map can be represented as a pair of maps or [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array):

Since `Map(a, b) = a -> b`, therefore `Bimap(a, b) = (Map(a, b), Map(b, a))`.

Internally, an associative array could be represented as either a pair of lists (i.e. `([a], [b])`) or a list of pairs (i.e. `[(a, b)]`) or [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or any other suitable data structure.

Let's implement a bidirectional map data structure using hash tables internally for efficiency:

```
function Bimap(keys, vals) {
    var length = Math.min(keys.length, vals.length);

    var valMap = this.lookupVal = Object.create(null);
    var keyMap = this.lookupKey = Object.create(null);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var val = vals[i];

        valMap[key] = val;
        keyMap[val] = key;
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
var bimap = new Bimap(["Earl", "John", "Shelia", "Lenny"], [85, 92, 87, 99]);

bimap.lookupVal["Lenny"]; // 99
bimap.lookupKey[99]; // "Lenny"
```

You can also add new key value pairs to the bidirectional map as follows:

```
Bimap.prototype.insert = function (keys, vals) {
    var length = Math.min(keys.length, vals.length);

    var valMap = this.lookupVal;
    var keyMap = this.lookupKey;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var val = vals[i];

        valMap[key] = val;
        keyMap[val] = key;
    }
};
```

You would use it as follows:

```
bimap.insert(["Jane"], [96]);

bimap.lookupVal["Jane"]; // 96
bimap.lookupKey[96]; // "Jane"
```

You can summarize bidirectional maps (such as finding min/max values, etc.) using `reduce`:

```
Bimap.prototype.reduceVals = function (inductive, basis) {
    var valMap = this.lookupVal, undefined;

    return basis === undefined ?
        Object.keys(valMap).reduce(callback) :
        Object.keys(valMap).reduce(callback, basis);

    function callback(proof, key) {
        return inductive(proof, valMap[key]);
    }
};
```

For example:

```
bimap.lookupKey[bimap.reduceVals(Math.min)]; // "Earl"
bimap.lookupKey[bimap.reduceVals(Math.max)]; // "Lenny"
```

Finally, most JavaScript engines now natively support the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure. Hence, you can implement `Bimap` in terms of that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create object of array in javascript like this

```
[{Name : "Test" , Score : 25},{Name : "Test Two" , Score : 35}]
```

Comment: He did say using two arrays {...}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using either associative arrays or multi-dimensional arrays. I would suggest taking a look at this tutorial: www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: He said he needs to use 2 arrays

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to match a name with a score in two different arrays. To do this, let's say they give you Lenny, first by using a `for` loop, you can loop through the first array, and look for his name, while keeping count on which index you're on.
The code would look like

```
int index = 0;
for(; index < array1.size(); index++)
```

When you find his name, just use that index that you found like `array2[index]` and you'll have your answer.